# How to specify the mappers failure threshold for a hadoop mapreduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I was set property **mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent = 10** for my job. My job was marked as FAILED after 159 mappers out of 162 (98%) total was successfully completed. What am i doing wrong?

I use Hadoop MR 2.6.0-cdh5.4.1 (75a690c8acab4f8da102c9d2e6b6405f25090302).

Comment: Have you also set  mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent

Comment: @NavneetKumar no, i don't. this option is deprecated long time, is not it?

Comment: @NavneetKumar That option was deprecated and the one you wrote is for the reducers, not for the mappers. Tolsi, how did you set the property?

Comment: @Balduz I set it using a property file and I can see it was setted in job.xml in my job tracker